# Assign values based on NA in other two variables of a data frame

Tags: r, na

given a data.frame, I'm trying to assign to a var3 the value of var4 if both var1 and var2 are simultaneously (meaning on the same row) missing values, otherwise var3 keeps its own value.

I tried this, but it does not work, any suggestions? Thanks a lot.

```
aaa<-function(x) {
  ifelse((is.na(x$var1)&is.na(x$var2)),
                x$var3<-x$var4, x$var3<-x$var3)
  return(x)
}
```

For example:

```
var1  var2  var3  var4
NA    NA    NA   1.610
 5    NA     4    6
 2     1    3.5   NA
 1    1.5   2.5   3
```

I would expect:

```
var1  var2  var3  var4
NA    NA   1.610 1.610
 5    NA     4    6
 2     1    3.5   NA
 1    1.5   2.5   3
```

Comment: Probably just `indx <- (is.na(x$var1) & is.na(x$var2)) ; x[indx, "var3"] <- x[indx, "var4"]`. Where `x` is your data frame.

Comment: @UmbertoMedicamento Your ifelse function can be  `aaa <- function(x) { x[,'var3'] <-with(x, ifelse(is.na(var1) & is.na(var2), var4, var3)); x}; aaa(df)`

Comment: @ David Arenburg Interesting, can you explain it? Anyhow, I tried but it doesn't work. My data are all numbers.

Comment: What is exactly not working? It works fine with the provided data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need in `ifelse` here because your "no" statement isn't doing anything. All you need to do is to find the correct rows and replace *only* them, while leaving all the rest untouched. Here's a simple base R approach

```
indx <- with(df, is.na(var1) & is.na(var2))
df[indx, "var3"] <- df[indx, "var4"]
```

Though, for efficiency and less key strokes, I'd recommend using the `data.table` package and update the values *by reference*

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[is.na(var1) & is.na(var2), var3 := var4]
```

Comment: @ David Arenburg My fault, it works. I didn't know about data.table, useful. I wonder I could learn to be so smart with R like you guys! Thanks

Comment: It's all about experience, you'll get there.